# Python fetching mailboxes with unicode characters

Tags: python, email, unicode

I'm trying to write custom mail agent.
I am trying to fetch all mails, but my mailbox has polish letter in mailboxnames...
So this code (cut all prints from listing):

```
def parse_list_response(self, line):
    list_response_pattern = re.compile(r'\((?P<flags>.*?)\) "(?P<delimiter>.*)" (?P<name>.*)')
    line=line.decode(encoding='utf_8')
    flags, delimiter, mailbox_name = list_response_pattern.match(line).groups()
    mailbox_name = mailbox_name.strip('"')
    return (flags, delimiter, mailbox_name)

def fetch_mails(self, from_who, since_when):
    server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.hostname)
    server.login(self.owner, self.password)
    rc, mailboxes = server.list()
    for line in mailboxes:
        mailbox=self.parse_list_response(line)[2]
        server.select(mailbox)
        try:
            messages = server.search('FROM "{}"'.format(from_who))
```

Gives me for example mailbox:

decoded = (\Flagged \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/Oznaczone gwiazdk&AQU-"

See: &AQU-... it is polish "ą"

Question is how to get rid of this? I cannot find how to decode this bytecode

Comment: What type of object is `line` when it's passed into the method? Could you add an example of a raw `line`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding is IMAP4 Modified UTF-7, which is a convention used for international mailbox names, as defined in RFC3501, section [5.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-5.1.3).

Unfortunately, the [imaplib](http://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#module-imaplib) module doesn't currently support it - although there are several issues on the python bug tracker that suggest that may change in the near future (e.g. [issue 5305](http://bugs.python.org/issue5305) and [issue 22598](http://bugs.python.org/issue22598)).

Anyway, in the meantime, it looks like you will have to find a third-party package to handle this (e.g. [imapclient](http://bitbucket.org/mjs0/imapclient/)).